# Kafka ordering guarantees

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I was going through `kafka` documentation and came across

> Guarantees
>
> At a high-level, Kafka gives the following guarantees:
>
> Messages sent by a producer to a particular topic partition will be
>   appended in the order they are sent. That is, if a record M1 is sent
>   by the same producer as a record M2, and M1 is sent first, then M1
>   will have a lower offset than M2 and appear earlier in the log. A
>   consumer instance sees records in the order they are stored in the
>   log. For a topic with replication factor N, we will tolerate up to N-1
>   server failures without losing any records committed to the log.

I had few questions.

1. Is it always guaranteed that `M1` will have a lower offset than `M2` ? what if `M1` is retried later than `M2` ?
2. I also understood from various documentations that ordering is not guaranteed, and the consumer has to deal with it.

Answer (score 7):

A possible scenario even with a single partition is:

- Producer sends `M1`
- Producer sends `M2`
- `M1` is not ack'ed on the first try due to some failure
- `M2` is delivered
- `M1` is delivered in a subsequent try.

One easy way to avoid this is through the producer config `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection=1`.

This of course has performance implications, so it should be used with caution.

Comment: Do you have some documentation or references for this scenario?

Comment: @Josh see `retries` here http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs .

Comment: @Josh I'm told that this is WRONG. For a single partition (within same consumer group) Kafka won't try to deliver M2 if it fails to deliver M1, (unless M1 reaches expiry).

Comment: @Kashyap do you have a reference for this?

Comment: @Kashyap following up as I reread: the producer won't know that M1 has failed. It will send M1, then M2, ..., MN, where N = 'max in flight requests per conn'. M1 takes a bad path and by the time it is realized that it needs to be resent, M2, .. MN have already been ACKd and sent. That's my understanding of one way the out of order scenario would occur.

Comment: @Josh, you're right. My statement should be qualified with "where AUTO_COMMIT is disabled". I.e. _For a single partition (within same consumer group) Kafka won't try to deliver M2 if it fails to deliver M1, (unless M1 reaches expiry) when AUTO_COMMIT is disabled._

Comment: You can also set enable.idempotence=true without the need to decreasing max.in.flight.requests.per.connection but you need to adjust other settings according to documentation:

Note that enabling idempotence requires max.in.flight.requests.per.connection to be less than or equal to 5, retries to be greater than 0 and acks must be ‘all’. If these values are not explicitly set by the user, suitable values will be chosen. If incompatible values are set, a ConfigException will be thrown.

Answer (score 5):

Please notice, that ordering guarantees apply at the **partition** level. So, if you have more than one partition in the topic, you'll need to set the same partition key for messages that you require to appear in order.

For example, if you want to collect messages from various sensors and sensor has it's id, then if you use this ID as message key, ordering of messages from every sensor will be guaranteed on consumers (as no sensor will write messages to more than 1 partition).

To answer your questions:

1. Yes, `M1` will have always offset lower than `M2`. The offsets are set by broker, so the time of message arrival at the broker is key here.
2. Ordering is not guaranteed on topic level only

Comment: about 1)  I doubt it wont be guranteed always ? what if M1 arrives later than M2 or M1 failed first and then retried later, meanwhile M2 is already arrived ?

Comment: If M1 arrives after M2, then it will be saved in order [M2, M1]. The same applies for failure situation - if your producer was unable to sent M1 before M2, then the ordering will be [M2, M1]. Kafka does not sort messages, it only stores them. If you want to ensure message ordering on the producer side, use synchronous API always (I mean `future.get()` or similar).

Comment: got it. so from the stmt `if a record M1 is sent by the same producer as a record M2, and **M1 is sent first**` --- this is guaranteed only if broker receives M1 first irrespective of producer sent M1 first or not.

Comment: Yes. I think the sentence assumes you use synchronous API (so producer can't send M2 if M1 was not received by brokers) or messages M1 and M2 are sent in one bulk message (so they will be saved in Kafka during one request)

Answer (score -3):

I have an article about deep understanding ordering guarantees provided by Kafka.
You can check it in my medium [post](https://medium.com/big-data-cloud-computing-and-distributed-systems/advanced-kafka-configurations-1-7965ad5ce1b2?source=friends_link&sk=952e222a8083313c11985dfd1d8de9f7).